# Difference between apache HttpClient execute(HttpUriRequest request) and execute(HttpHost target, HttpRequest request)

Tags: java, apache, http

Guys, 
 you knows the difference between Apache HttpClient execute(HttpUriRequest request) and execute(HttpHost target, HttpRequest request)

Like:
   execute(new HttpGet("http://hostname.com/this/is/a/test/")
   execute(new HttpHost("hostname.com", 80, "http"), new HttpGet("/this/is/a/test/"));

Answer (score 0):

These are overloads for execute() method to generate URL different ways.

Comment: execute(new HttpGet("http://hostname.com/this/is/a/test/") can get the right response.But execute(new HttpHost("hostname.com", 80, "http"), new HttpGet("/this/is/a/test/")) can't. They are different?